# Elementary question in differential topology

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $p$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Is the variety $Z(p)$ a $n-1$ dimensional manifold?another words why is that $o=(0,\cdots,0)$ a regular point for $p$ viewed as a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Choosing $p(x,y)=xy$ the zero locus $V(p)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is the coordinate cross. Is this a two dimensional manifold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the implicit function theorem, that for a smooth $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and a *regular value* $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(p)$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $m-n$.

In general, if $p$ is not necessarily regular, $f^{-1}(p)$ needs not be a manifold.

Comment: Thats a good point

Answer (score 2):

In general, no. $Z(x^2+y^2)= \{(0,0)\}$ is not a $1$-dimensional manifold.